# Data Integration Specialist Challenge 7 not completing

Tags: soap-api, integration, trailhead, superbadges

I am trying to complete the challenge 7 "Synchronize Salesforce project data with Square Peg's external billing system".

However I get the following error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  The SOAP call to
>   the BillingService did not return the correct response. Please check
>   your configurations and code.

When I trigger the SOAP Call manually I get the success message returned from the external system. Debugging the *billProjectResponse_element* in the *BillingServiceProxy* Class I see the following:

```
billProjectResponse_element:[apex_schema_type_info=(http://salesforce.com/th/invoice-web-service, true, false), field_order_type_info=(status), status=ok, status_type_info=(status, http://salesforce.com/th/invoice-web-service, null, 1, 1, false)]
```

so the **status=ok** part tells me the call is successful.

However the error message keeps coming. Since this superbadge is part of the Platform Dev 2 certification, I am a bit hesitant about sharing my code but it is behaving as described and updating the project record as designed. Only while checking the Challenge I get this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solved - at the time of writing the provided endpoint to be called was not giving the correct response structure. The problem should not arise anymore.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem today, can you elaborate on what the SOAP service was responding with? The SOAP call works from my triggers, but when I run the challenge/test, I don't even see any debug logs, and get this message.